# Polymorphic_url links for nested comment resource routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I am having trouble getting my nested routes to work how I want them to.

```
resources :posts do
  member do
    put "like", to: "posts#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "posts#downvote"
  end
  resources :comments do
  member do
    put "like", to: "comments#upvote"
    put "dislike", to: "comments#downvote"
  end
end
end
```

How do I link to these with polymorphic_url / path?  I have read the APIs but I'm still having problems?

Currently in my Posts index view:

```
   <div id="posts">
   <% @posts.each do |post| %>
    <h2><%= link_to post.title, post %></h2>
    <%= simple_format post.content %>
    <%= current_user.username %>
    <p>
      Tag: <%= raw post.tag_list.map { |t| link_to t, tag_path(t) }.join(', ') %>
     </p>

      <div>
  <%= link_to "up", like_post_path(post), method: :put %>
  <%= link_to "down", dislike_post_path(post), method: :put %>
  <%= post.score %>
  </div>

  <p><%= link_to "Edit Post", edit_post_path(post) %></p>
  <p><%= link_to "Comment", new_polymorphic_url([post, @comment]) %></p>
  <p><%= link_to "View Comments", polymorphic_url([post, @comments]) %></p>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

Right now "Comment" link takes you to new_post_path

and "View Comments" link takes you to posts_path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change these lines:

```
<p><%= link_to "Comment", new_polymorphic_url([post, @comment]) %></p>
<p><%= link_to "View Comments", polymorphic_url([post, @comments]) %></p>
```

to this:

```
<p><%= link_to "Comment", new_post_comment_path(post) %></p>
<p><%= link_to "View Comments", post_comments_path(post) %></p>
```